# C# How can i remove newline characters from binary?

Tags: c#

Basically i have binary data, i dont mind if it's unreadable but im writing it to a file which is parsed and so it's importance newline characters are taken out.

I thought i had done the right thing when i converted to string....

```
byte[] b = (byte[])SubKey.GetValue(v[i]);
s = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(b);
```

and then removed the newlines

```
String t = s.replace("\n","")
```

but its not working ?

Comment: Depends on what kind of new lines you're dealing with, in windows they are normally "\r\n", not just "\n". Environment.NewLine might be usefull if you want some platform independence.

Answer (score 6):

Newline might be \r\n, and your binary data might not be ASCII encoded.

Comment: What do i do if its not? I just need to make sure no newlines appear. I thought converting it to a string would then allow me to use the String.replace etc

Comment: Well, what do you know about the binary data, where do you get it from? If it's not ASCII encoded, you could try Encoding.Default.GetString, or Encoding.Unicode.GetString, or whatever you think could be right. Then remove all occurences of \r\n.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly newline (`Environment.Newline`) is usually two characters on Windows, do you mean removing single carriage-return or line-feed characters?

Secondly, applying a text encoding to binary data is likely to lead to unexpected conversions. E.g. what will happen to buyes of the binary data that do not map to ASCII characters?

Comment: It doesnt matter if the data changes slightly, im performing integrity checking so as long as whatever i set the data to doesnt change in the future, its not a problem.

but im writing this data to file and i cannot parse because sometimes values have lots of 'newlines'

Answer (score 0):

New line character may be `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n` **depends on operating system type**, in order this is markers for `Linux`, `Macintosh` and `Windows`.

But if you say you file is binary from what you know they **have newlines in ASCII** in her content?

If this is binary file this **may be a some struct**, if this they struct you after remove newline characters **shift left all data after the this newline and corrupt data in her**.

Comment: The data is coming from the windows registry and i am using XP 32 :)

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine removing the bytes in a binary chunk which correspond the line feeds would actually corrupt the binary data, thereby making it useless.

Perhaps you'd be better off using base64 encoding, which will produce ASCII-safe output.

Answer (score 0):

If this is text data, then load it as text data (using the correct encoding), replace it as as a string, and re-encode it (using the correct encoding). For *some* encodings you might be able to do a swap at the file level (without decoding/encoding), but I wouldn't bet on it.

If this is any other binary representation, you will **have** to know the exact details. For example, it is common (but not for certain) for strings embedded in part of a binary file to have a length prefix. If you change the data without changing the length prefix, you've just corrupted the file. And to change the length prefix you need to know the format (it might be big-endian/little-endian, any fixed number of bytes, or the prefix itself could be variable length). Or it might be delimited. Or there might be relative offsets scattered through the file that all need fixing.

Just as likely; you could *by chance* have the same byte sequence in the binary that *doesn't* represent a newline; you could be completely trashing the data.